# Joins with PHP and MySQL with only returns by specified value?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I just can't seem to grasp the `JOINS` concept as beautiful as it sounds. At this point I am not sure which of the following are my issue, but I would really love some help figuring this out. I have read several posts on here, and even took the W3Schools test alongside reading materials, yet I can't come to a solution. By a book? Sure, which one? I am not opposed to learning, just don't know where to start.

The issue is I have three tables that have all the information in the world I need, but I have only been able to match a single row (i.e. if profile.person = user.id). That returns the ability for me to `LEFT JOIN` the persons name where the profile.person number value was a match so that when the table is displayed it does not show numbers. Makes sense, but when I go a step farther I feel like Alice in Wonderland and confused.

What I am trying to do is take story, pull the posts of that story, identify the series the story is from, and then the user who has posted that story.

My tables look like this:

```
Series Table
PID INT, name VARCHAR, episodes INT
(episodes = # of stories in series)

Stories Table
PID INT, name VARCHAR, series INT, posts INT
(both series and posts = # items under them)

Storyparts Table
PID INT, story INT, position INT, port INT, content MEDIUMTEXT
(story is the ID of the story it belongs too, position is the order it should be
 displayed in, port is the ID of the character who is telling the story,
 content is the post itself (text))

Characters Table
PID INT, name VARCHAR, faction INT, imgport VARCHAR, imgmain VARCHAR, age INT,
hometown VARCHAR, bio MEDIUMTEXT
(both imgport and imgmain store the file names of their images "Portrait and Main")
```

What I am trying to do it load a story and display its `name`, the the `name` of the series it is from and display the `imgport` of the character followed by the `name` of the character and then finally the `content`. I am fine with displaying them once I have them stored to a variable, my question is how the heck do I do that? Is the problem with my tables? Did I not gather enough information to make it work, or is there a way to pull all information from one table basses on a single value stored in another?

The code I have so far: (I have while loop after this and and if statement to filter out the unwanted post, but I am sure this is well beyond good practice.)

```
if ($getStories = $db->query("SELECT stories.*,
              series.name as series
              FROM stories
              LEFT JOIN series ON stories.series = series.pid")
                              or die($db->error)) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db->query("
   select st.name as story_name, se.name as series_name, 
   c.imgport, c.name, sp.content from series as se 
   left join stories as st on se.pid = st.pid
   left join character as c on se.pid = c.pid
   left join storyparts as sp on se.pid = sp.pid");
```

I believe this will do what you want. If you need to join more than one table... then add more joins :)

Comment: Ok that looks great! Now if I wanted to call one of the variables after the fact how would I do so. When you use the 'as c' does that mean I would write 

`while ($row = $getStories->fetch_object()) {$pid = $row->PID;$name = $row->name;$series = $row->se;}`

Comment: Added some aliases on your select so you can do $row->story_name and $row->series_name